# Pass data from table view to view controller

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8

i have a table view that lists data from a parse.com class i want to pass the data that the person clicks and display the whole row formatted in a view controller on the next page

```
  - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
  if (self) {
    // Customize the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"Exibitor";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.textKey = @"name";

    // The title for this table in the Navigation Controller.
    self.title = @"Exhibitor";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 6;
 }

 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Exibitor"];
 //[query whereKey:@"playername" equalTo:@"Sean Plott"];
 [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The count request succeeded. Log the count
        NSLog(@"there are %d entries", count);
    } else {
        // The request failed
    }
 }];


 return self;
 }




 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [self setTitle:@"Exibitor List"];


 // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
 // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

 // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view      controller.
 // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
  }
```

in the Exibitor row there is comapny name address web site (that i want to be a link) phone number. and more.

so say the user click Exibitor number 1 the next page will open it will be a view controller with all the information.

Comment: So lets sum up, you have a tableview which contains a list of company with it's shorten information. Now you want if when user tap on a row, a new view will come up and display the company's full info. That's it?

Comment: yes thats it... i know it involves an array but im new to this so any help would be greatfull

Comment: Did you come to populate your array with companies? You came to understand this part?

Comment: no im still trying to do that

Comment: How come you can't even maintain your data but you want to pass it to an another viewcontroller? No offense but such question proves that you didn't try or at least identify your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the array[row selected] result to next view controller and parse your detail to populate your view controller. Also this is that array with which you populate your tableview Controller. Anything else then let me know